# Is $id:(C[0, 1], d_1) \to (C[0, 1], d_2)$ homeomorphism? Yes/No

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(C[0, 1], d_1)$  and $(C[0, 1], d_2)$  be the metric spaces where

$$d_1(f, g) = \sup_{x∈[0,1]} |f(x) − g(x)|\\
d_2(f, g) =\int_{0}^{1}|f(x) − g(x)|dx \,$$

Is  $id:(C[0, 1], d_1)   \to (C[0, 1], d_2)$  homeomorphism?

My attempt : I think No. For homeomorphism  $f^{-1}$  must be continious.Here  $d_1$ is complete  but $d_2$ is not complete.  So i think  $f^{-1}$ is not continious.

For example  take  $f(x)=x^n $ and $g=0$.Then $d_2(f,g)=0$  but $d_1(f,g)=1\neq 0$

Comment: Why did you delete your definition of $(f_n)$? That was useful.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  sir actually i thought that the example was not useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuous functions preserve convergence, therefore, if $id$ is a homeomorphism, then a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f$ in $d_1$ iff it converges to $f$ in $d_2$.

However, there is a sequence that converges to 0 in $d_2$ but not in $d_1$. Let $f_n$ be the function that goes from 1 to 0 linearly on $[0, 1/n)$, and then is constant 0 on $[1/n, 1]$. For large $n$, $\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx$ is arbitrarily small, while $sup(|f_n(x) - 0|)$ is always 1.

Therefore, $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $d_2$ but not in $d_1$, so $id$ is not a homeomorphism.